# Solution to JSX props not using inline arrow functions?

Tags: javascript, react-native, ecmascript-6, jsx

I recently found out the reasons why I shouldn't use inline arrow functions for component props, but I do not know what the recommended solutions are. Here is an example of me using a function:

```
  renderSectionFooter(isSpecialFooter) {
    return (
      <SomeFooter
        onPress={
          isSpecialFooter
            ? () => this.toggleModalVisibility('specialFooterIsVisible')
            : () => this.toggleModalVisibility('boringFooterIsVisible')
        }
      />
    );
  }
```

which allows me to have a very simple and clean toggler function:

`toggleModalVisibility(modalIsVisible) {
    this.setState({ [modalIsVisible]: !this.state[modalIsVisible] });
  }`

The only way around this I can see is to create a special function for each "footer", but in my opinion this goes against best practices in having similar functions.

Comment: regardless of `true` and `false` your onPress will trigger same method `toggleModalVisibility`. So instead why not moving the check inside `toggleModalVisibility`?

Comment: wouldn't `this.toggleModalVisibility(isSpecialFooter ? 'specialFooterIsVisible' : 'boringFooterIsVisible')` make more sense to use?

Comment: at any rate, your only other alternative is to use an `IFFE` to pass `isSpecialFooter` and return a function using it when pressed

Comment: OR, you could create a proper function outside of the render to handle the logic, which I believe, is what's supposed to be done

Comment: Could you link us to those reasons not to use inline arrow functions for props?

Answer (score 0):

You should not use inline arrow function to pass the required value. Best practice is to bind the required value with the function. You can also bind value conditionally. This allows the single handler for both the conditions the way you have mentioned. Consider below code for the same:

```
renderSectionFooter(isSpecialFooter) {
   return (
     <SomeFooter
        onPress={this.toggleModalVisibility.bind(this, isSpecialFooter ? 'specialFooterIsVisible' : 'boringFooterIsVisible')}
      />
   );
}
```

Comment: wouldnt this cause the same problem as an inline function, source: https://about.usps.com/postal-bulletin/2007/html/pb22218/kit1_011.html

Comment: No it won't cause same problem as inline function because in case of inline functions each time component renders the new function will be created.

While here we are binding required value with the declared `toggleModalVisibility` function handler itself.

Let me know it it's still not clear.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use a method that is defined out of `render()` method and in class body like this in this way you will avoid the disadvantages of inline functions and you can use arrow function and you don't need to bind functions. You can use a function as below:

```
_someFunc = (isSpecialFooter) = () => {
    if (isSpecialFooter) {
        this.toggleModalVisibility('specialFooterIsVisible');
    } else {
        this.toggleModalVisibility('boringFooterIsVisible')
    }
}

renderSectionFooter(isSpecialFooter) {
    return (
      <SomeFooter
        onPress={_someFunc(isSpecialFooter)}
      />
    );
  }
```